# SQL query get datasets where having count(*) = 0

Tags: sql

I'm searching for a good way to search through all datasets in a table and select all, where count(*) = 0.

Example table:

```
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
| id | msg                  | username | submission |
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
| 1  | hello                | userA    | 2020-08-12 |
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
| 2  | demo text            | userB    | 2020-08-13 |
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
| 3  | demo text2           | userC    | 2020-08-15 |
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
| 4  | hiho                 | userC    | 2020-08-16 |
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
| 5  | something inmportant | userC    | 2020-08-16 |
+----+----------------------+----------+------------+
```

what I want is to output all usernames, who do NOT have a submission between e.g. 2020-08-14 and 2020-08-15. So I want to see userA and userB in the output, but NOT userC. By filter simply with submission not between 2020-08-14 00:00:00 and 2020-08-15 00:00:00 it will still show me userC, because there is an entry from 2020-08-16 - but I do NOT want userC in the output.

Using `having count(*) = 0` sadly also doesn't work.

Any ideas how to make it, if possible, without any T-SQL/cursor things etc? If not, I'm also open for T-SQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select username from tablename
where username not in 
     (select distinct username from tablename where submission>='2020-08-14' 
and submission<='2020-08-15')
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple method is aggregation:

```
select username
from t
group by username
having sum(case when submission between '2020-08-14' and '2020-08-15' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Note that this does not return duplicates.

If you have a *separate* table of users (and names), then I suggest `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from submissions s
                  where s.username = u.username and
                        s.submission between '2020-08-14' and '2020-08-15'
                 );
```

This should be very fast with an index on `(username, submission)`.